# Functional component definition inside class component's render() method, state resets when created through JSX, but not when called directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I define a functional component inside of a class component's `render()` method, then the component's state is getting reset every time the class component's `render()` method is called. If I call the functional component directly though, the state does not reset.

Look at the following example:

```
import React from 'react';
import Counter from './Counter'

const MilliCounter = ({name}) => {
    return <Counter name={name} initial={1e6} />
};

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            flag: false
        }
    }

    onButtonClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({flag: !this.state.flag});
    };

    render() {
        const HundoCounter = ({name}) => {
            return <Counter name={name} initial={100} />
        };

        return (<div>
            <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Change State</button>
            <div>{`Flag: ${this.state.flag}`}</div>
            <HundoCounter name="Component Def Inside render() - Hundo JSX"/>
            {HundoCounter({name: 'Component Def Inside render() - Hundo Function Call'})}
            <MilliCounter name="Component Def Outside render() - Milli JSX"/>
            {MilliCounter({name: 'Component Def Outside render() - Milli Function Call'})}
        </div>)
    }
}

export default App;
```

```
import * as React from 'react'

export default class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            count: props.initial
        }
    }

    onButtonClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{border: '1px solid black', margin: '1rem', padding: '0.67rem'}}>
                <h6>{this.props.name}</h6>
                <p>Count: {this.state.count}</p>
                <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Click Me</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here's a video showing the demo app in action. 
https://i.imgur.com/WfS8DXJ.mp4

As you can see, when the button is clicked it changes the flag to true which forces a re-render. During this the state of the functional component `HundoCounter` defined with JSX is reset, but not the one that is called directly.

It makes sense to me that the state would reset, because it's creating a new definition of `HundoCounter` every time `render()` is called. How come the state for the `HundoCounter` that's called directly as a function does not get reset?

Comment: this is bad practice. why are you doing this? for experiment?

Comment: @technophyle Yes for an experiment. In a larger codebase today I was trying to figure out why my component's state was getting reset so I tried calling it like a function to see if it made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is because you're re-rendering the parent component, which then resets the initial={100} to set it back to 100, when the child component is re-rendered due to the parent re-render.

Which is the intended behaviour

As for why the second one isn't resetting i don't know, but it seems odd that it is not, since it's value should also be reset

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems odd. I think it is related with React's `reconciliation` and `diff` algorithm. When I add the key property to Counter component it behaves what we expect.

```
 const HundoCounter = ({ name }) => {
  console.log("hundo function")
  return <Counter key={Math.random()} name={name} initial={100} />
};
```

I think render() method is called and the diff algorithm recurses on the previous result and the new result and somehow function surround the component and behaves like it is the same component. Btw I like this experiment :)